# Changing write permissions for jailed SFTP denies login

Tags: permissions, chroot, sftp

I have scouted over many websites and forums on how to setup an SFTP user that is jailed to a certain directory using CHROOT. Here are the steps I have followed but I can't seem to get write permissions to work.

**Setup**

**sshd_config**

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp


Match group webmaster
        X11Forwarding no
        ChrootDirectory %h
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

**Create Folder**

```
mkdir /var/www/sites
```

**Create User and Group**

```
useradd uploader
passwd uploader
usermod -d /var/www/sites uploader
groupadd webmaster uploader
groupadd www-data uploader
```

**Permissions and Ownership**

```
chown root:root /var/www
chmod 755 /var/www/sites
```

Now with these settings the user uploader is able to SFTP into the home directory but is unable to write to the directory.

There are 2 typical errors that occur, I either can't login or I don't have write permissions.

**Login Error**

```
Error:    Network error: Software caused connection abort
Error:    Could not connect to server


Changing permissions of /var/www/sites to 775 or 777 causes login error.
chown /var/www/sites to uploader:root causes login error.
chwon root:webmaster or root:www-data I have no write permissions
```

I am at odds end trying to figure this out and if anyone could point me into the right direction I would be greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Found out the solution. The user is jailed to `/var/www/sites`. I then created another folder `/var/www/sites/site1`.

I use:

```
chown root:webmaster /var/www/sites/site1 
chmod 775 /var/www/sites/site1
```

This enabled the home directory to have the correct permissions to login and then be able to write to the next folder up.

If the user needs write access to `/var/www/sites`, then you must jail the user at `/var/www` which has `root:root` ownership and permissions of 755.  You then need to give `/var/www/sites` ownership of root:(your group) and permissions of 775.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the greatest solution is:

```
mkdir /var/www/sites/myfirstuser/hisownsite
mkdir /var/www/sites/myseconduser/hisownsite
```

...

```
chown root:root /var/www/sites /var/www/sites/{myfirstuser,myseconduser} && chmod 755 /var/www/sites/{myfirstuser,myseconduser}

chmod 775 /var/www/sites/myfirstuser/hisownsite
chmod 775 /var/www/sites/myseconduser/hisownsite
chgrp www-data /www/sites/myfirstuser/hisownsite /var/www/sites/myseconduser/hisownsite
```

Add the users:

```
useradd -d /var/www/sites/myfirstuser -s /bin/false -g www-data  dev1
useradd -d /var/www/sites/myseconduser -s /bin/false -g www-data dev2
passwd dev1
passwd dev2
```

Then, for each user you have created, add an ssh tag like this:
(you could also use the "Match Group" directive as in your example instead of "Match User")

```
Match User dev1
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no

Match user dev2
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

So you can manage all users you need in a chrooted environment.

Hth,
Fabrizio

Comment: Re your final code block: `Match`es support multiple targets in comma-separated lists, so we could greatly simplify/tidy that by having a single set of overrides for both users, by the heading `Match User dev1,dev2`

Comment: So how do you set it so they are locked to the folder they have read/write access to?